# How to output using recursive (parents -> children -> grandchildren)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery, recursive-query

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
    persID      INT IDENTITY(1,1)   PRIMARY KEY,
    persFName   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    persLName   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    persDOB     DATE,
    motherID    INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES person(persID),
    fatherID    INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES person(persID),
    persDOD     DATE,
    persGender  CHAR(1),
)

CREATE TABLE COUPLE
(
    coupleID    INT     IDENTITY(1,1)   PRIMARY KEY,
    alphaSpouse INT     NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES person(persID),
    omegaSpouse INT     NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES person(persID),
    coupleStart DATE    NOT NULL,
    coupleEnd   DATE,
)

INSERT INTO person (persFName, persLName, persDOB, motherID, fatherID, persDOD, persGender) VALUES
('Jim', 'Smith', '1920-05-15', NULL, NULL, '2001-04-21','M'),
('Agnes', 'Smith', '1922-09-21', NULL, NULL, '2003-06-01','F'),
('Linda', 'Howard', '1949-03-20', 2, 1, NULL,'F'),
('Helen', 'Bradley', '1942-11-28', 2, 1, NULL,'F'),
('Jim', 'Smith', '1953-02-10', 2, 1, NULL,'M'),
('Stephen', 'Smith', '1957-01-13', 2, 1, '2005-05-25','M'),
('Daniel', 'Smith', '1961-11-28', 2, 1, NULL,'M'),
('Michelle', 'Smith', '1963-07-02', NULL, NULL, NULL,'F'),
('Anne', 'Smith', '1958-04-22', NULL, NULL, NULL,'F'),
('Josh', 'Smith', '1990-01-28', 8, 7, NULL,'M'),
('Stephanie', 'Smith', '1992-05-18', 8, 7, NULL,'F'),
('Rachel', 'Smith', '1996-11-05', 8, 7, NULL,'F'),
('Reg', 'Howard', '1949-07-07', NULL, NULL, NULL,'M'),
('Richard', 'Howard', '1972-12-26', 3, 13, NULL,'M'),
('Phillip', 'Howard', '1975-06-01', 3, 13, NULL,'M'),
('Robert', 'Bradley', '1939-03-07', NULL, NULL, NULL,'M'),
('Matthew', 'Bradley', '1964-10-26', 4, 16, '2001-04-27','M'),
('Yvonne', 'Bradley', '1966-11-28', 4, 16, NULL,'F'),
('James', 'Bradley', '1971-01-26', 4, 16, NULL,'M'),
('Anna', 'Reuper', '1918-01-27', NULL, NULL, NULL,'F'),
('Ludwig', 'Reuper', '1923-07-01', NULL, NULL, '2001-07-01','M'),
('Heinz', 'Reuper', '1965-01-28', 20, 21, NULL,'M'),
('Veronica', 'Reuper', '1959-04-01', 20, 21, NULL,'F'),
('Marco', 'Johnson', '1958-09-04', NULL, NULL, NULL,'M'),
('Francesca', 'Reuper', '1990-11-01', 23, 24, NULL,'F'),
('Lou', 'Jung', '1940-02-03', NULL, NULL, NULL,'M'),
('Tammi', 'Sinclair', '1971-02-03', NULL, NULL, NULL,'F'),
('Lori', 'Navarro', '1973-12-15', NULL, NULL, NULL,'F'),
('Kattie', 'Paine', '1980-10-31', NULL, NULL, NULL,'F');


INSERT INTO couple (alphaSpouse,omegaSpouse, coupleStart, coupleEnd) VALUES
(1,2,'1940-05-22', NULL),
(3,13,'1969-07-30', '1973-10-01'),
(3,26,'1980-01-10', '1982-12-01'),
(4,16,'1963-04-05', NULL),
(6,9,'1979-06-21', NULL),
(7,8,'1987-09-14', NULL),
(20,21,'1936-10-26', NULL),
(23,24,'1988-05-01', '1997-07-01'),
(19,27,'1992-10-31', '1993-01-31'),
(19,28,'1995-08-18', '1997-04-27'),
(19,29,'2015-09-19', NULL);
```

I'm trying to list all the people who have grandchildren and how many grandchildren they each have. I'd like an ouput like this;
[image: an output like this]

I attempted to do it below, but I got stuck trying to COUNT grandkids outside the WHERE subquery.. was I even on the right track?

```
SELECT grandp.persFName + ' ' + grandp.persLName, COUNT(grandkids.persID) 
FROM person grandp
JOIN person child ON grandp.persID = child.motherID OR  grandp.persID = child.fatherID
WHERE child.persID IN (SELECT grandkids.motherID
                        FROM person grandkids
                        union
                        SELECT grandkids.fatherID
                        FROM person grandkids)
GROUP BY grandp.persFName + ' ' + grandp.persLName
```

Comment: can you post some sample data ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot, I just added it

Answer (score 2):

When you have hierarchical data like yours, it's best approached with common table expressions. This will allow you to build the hierarchical data into a form that you can later use - in your example, to count grandchildren. You can take advantage of building data by levels or distance from the root.

```
with temp (persid, ancestorid, level) as (
  select persid, persid as ancestorid, 0 as level
  from person
  where motherid is null and fatherid is null

  union all

  select person.persid, temp.ancestorid, temp.level + 1 as level
  from person
  inner join temp on temp.persid = person.motherid or temp.persid = person.fatherid
)

select temp.ancestorid as persid, 
  person.persFName + ' ' + person.persLName as name,
  count(*)
from temp
inner join person
on temp.ancestorid = person.persid
where level = 2
group by temp.ancestorid, person.persFName, person.persLName
```

The query builds a CTE of each person, it's ancestor and the level (0 = grandparents, 2 = grandchildren). You can then easily count grandchildren for each ancestor.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99c97/2

(Note: I left the couple table out as it's not needed here).

Answer (score 1):

Try this I just used common table expressions recursively to get the result

```
;WITH Allpersons AS
(
 SELECT persID AS Id
,persFName+' '+persLName AS Name 
,fatherID
,motherID
FROM PERSON

)
SELECT
 GrandFatherCTE.Name 
 ,COUNT(GrandFatherCTE.Id ) AS CountOfChild
FROM Allpersons AllPersonsCTE
INNER JOIN
Allpersons ParentsCte
ON
AllPersonsCTE.fatherID = ParentsCte.Id
OR
AllPersonsCTE.motherID = ParentsCte.Id
INNER JOIN
Allpersons GrandFatherCTE
ON
ParentsCte.fatherID = GrandFatherCTE.Id
OR
ParentsCte.motherID = GrandFatherCTE.Id
INNER JOIN
COUPLE 
ON
GrandFatherCTE.Id = COUPLE.alphaSpouse
OR
GrandFatherCTE.Id = COUPLE.omegaSpouse

GROUP BY
GrandFatherCTE.Name 
,COUPLE.coupleID
ORDER BY 
 CountOfChild  ASC
,COUPLE.coupleID ASC
```